# how to customise the Get property?

Tags: c#

How do I customise the get property only without changing the set property?

```
public DateTime lastprocessed { get; set; }
```

I want to return the datetime in local timestamp as its stored in UTC.

Comment: in that case, you cannot use auto implemented properties. revert to the normal syntax.

Comment: That's like @Aominè said. What you can do, though, is making the `get` protected, and creating a method (e.g `GetLastProcessed()`) and return the local **date** as you wish. That would help you avoid acessing the property value directly, forcing you to use the method.

Comment: In addition to the methods listed below, you could just add a new property, `LastProcessedUTC`, and make `lastprocessed`. You do want to be careful about knowing the `DateTime.Kind` value when returning values.

In general, when I get to needing to apply processing, I tend to avoid auto-properties. They're not fit for all use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you could get is that in `C#` 6 and later, you can initialize auto-implemented properties similarly to fields:

```
public DateTime FirstName { get; set; } = // your value here;
```

if you wish to perform some logic prior to assignment then you can create a method to do the logic and assign the result like so:

```
public DateTime FirstName { get; set; } = doLogic();
```

The last option would just be the classic `get;` `set;`

```
public DateTime lastprocessed
{
       get
       {   
           // some logic ...
           return // some value; 
       }

       set
       {
           // some logic ...
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is going to be to use either what @Alisson suggested in the comment (`protected get` with a method to access its value) or a `private` backer:

```
    private DateTime _lastprocessed;
    public DateTime lastprocessed
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastprocessed.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime();
        }
        set
        {
            _lastprocessed = value;
        }
    }
```

When you apply formatting to the `get` accessor without a backing field and try to create a `set` accessor, you end up with a *Stack Overflow* error because the `set` will endlessly invoke itself, attempting to set the value of the property.

If you add an initializer to the auto property, this is fine for setting the initial value of `lastprocessed`, but I think you will end up running into to trouble, assuming you intend on reassigning the value of `lastprocessed`. Even if you define a function for the initializer, you don't have a way of accessing the value that is being assigned to `lastprocessed`.